# Is it acceptable to convert the optimized control input state (acceleration) from my Model Predictive Controller to position

Tags: control, pid, force, state, mpc

Good day,

I hope you are well. I currently have an MPC position controller that optimizes a set of control input accelerations given a trajectory.

u = [Ux_dot_dot Uy_dot_dot, Uz_dot_odt]

However what my low level controller (next block that does inverse kinematics and Computed Torque Control) requires are position inputs u = [Ux, Uy, Uz].

Is it alright for me to convert the acceleration output from the MPC controller into position using this equation

x(k) = 1/2*acceleration(k-1)*Ts^2 + velocity(k-1)*Ts + x(k-1)

I saw a lecture paper converting his acceleration to velocity as the motor controller only accepts velocity inputs but I couldn't find that paper anymore.